# Replace not functioning

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying simple replace to delete the brackets and text within it but it's not working.
Please help. My code is:

```
Dim r As Integer
For r = 2 To 30
   Cells(r, 3) = Replace(Cells(r, 3), "(*)", "")
   MsgBox Cells(r, 3)
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ordinary `replace` function doesn't take wildcards `*` - but for some reason, `Range.Replace` does.

```
Dim rng1 as Range

    Set rng1 = Range(Cells(2,3), Cells(30,3))
    rng1.Replace What:= "(*)", Replacement:= "", LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

(Obviously you probably won't need to use all of those named parameters...)

Comment: Why do you loop through 1-row ranges? wouldn't one range-replace be enough?

Comment: @Turo haha you're right sorry, I was too busy concentrating on doing exactly what the OP's code did step-by-step to notice!!

Comment: OP would still need the loop if they still wanted message boxes for each replaced value ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Range.Replace` function and make the replacement at once:

```
Sub testReplace()
  Dim rngR As Range
  Set rngR = Range("C2:C30")
   rngR.Replace "(*)", ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Both options are perfect!

Comment: @Vakhs: What 'options' are you referring to? I only supplied a solution able to replace all occurrences at once, without any iteration. And also, I tried to suggest that declaring variables would be a good habit. It does not present two options... Am I missing something? :)

Comment: Even Spencer has updated his code and removed the loop. So now both the solutions are similar... I have used yours where Range"C2:C30" is directly defined. Thank you!

Comment: @Vakhs: I did not understand what you  mean by 'options'. Now I understand that you compared my answer with another one. OK.  It is up to you what solution to choose like accepted answer. **I do not care too much about this aspect**. What I know is that, when I posted my answer, nobody else used this way. Otherwise, I wouldn't come with another solution. In the way you put it in discussion, everybody may post the best answer collecting the best from the other ones...